# Filtrar por un queryset con 2 kwargs

Tags: django

Tengo una URL en la que paso 2 parámetros:

Edicionlist.hmtl

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{% url "inscripcion:inscripciones_personas_edicion-list" programa=element.id edicion=element.edicion%}">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Ver inscritos
 </a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.InscripcionesIndexView.as_view(), name="index"),

url(r'^inscripcion_personas_edicion/(?P<programa>\d+)/(?P<edicion>\d+)/$', views.InscripcionesPorEdicionListView.as_view(), name="inscripciones_personas_edicion-list"),
]
```

Pues bien, ahora quiero filtrar los resultados del modelo por esos 2 campos:

```
views.py

class InscripcionesPorEdicionListView(ListView):
template_name = "appinscripciones/inscripciones/Inscripcioneslist.html"
model = Inscritos
group_required = ['Básico', 'Administrador']
login_url = "auth-login"

def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(InscripcionesPorEdicionListView, self).get_queryset()
    return qs.filter(programa__exact=self.kwargs['programa']).filter(edicion__exact=self.kwargs['edicion'])
```

Pero solo me filtra por el primero, que sería programa. ¿Alguien sabría decirme que estoy haciendo mal en el `Queryset`?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Has intentado pasar el id de la edicion en la url en vez de pasar un objeto como tal?... es decir en tu url del html colocar, `edicion=element.edicion.id`

Comment: Si, y no funciona...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, lo único que veo en tu pregunta es lo siguiente:

En tu template:

```
...
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{% url "inscripcion:inscripciones_personas_edicion-list" programa=element.id edicion=element.edicion%}">
...
```

Debes cambiar a enteros, por lo que debes poner el id, porque en tus `urls.py` estas buscando una expresión regular con `\d+`, por lo que tu url solo busca por números, por lo que cámbialo a:

```
...
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="{% url "inscripcion:inscripciones_personas_edicion-list" programa=element.id edicion=element.edicion.id %}">
...
```

Ahora, en tu método `get_queryset()` observo cosas innecesarias, entre esas, hacer un filtro por un objeto con el `lookup` `__exact`, ya que por defecto ese es el que usa django, por lo que es lo mismo escribir `Model.objects.filter(nombre__exact=a)` y esto `Model.objects.filter(nombre=a)`. Segundo, si te estan mandando un id en la url, debes buscar y filtrar a partir de ese id.

Por lo que tu método quedaría algo así:

```
...
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(InscripcionesPorEdicionListView, self).get_queryset()
    programa = get_object_or_404(Programa, id=self.kwargs.get('programa', 0))
    edicion = get_object_or_404(Edicion, id=self.kwargs.get('edicion', 0))
    return qs.filter(programa=programa, edicion=edicion)
...
```

Así seria para asegurar que te el programa y la edición exista, pero para reducir el numero de consultas puedes hacerlo así:

```
...
def get_queryset(self):
    qs = super(InscripcionesPorEdicionListView, self).get_queryset()
    programa_id = self.kwargs.get('programa', 0)
    edicion_id = self.kwargs.get('edicion', 0)
    return qs.filter(programa_id=programa, edicion_id=edicion)
...
```

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda, comenta :)

Comment: Ha funcionado a la perfección, gracias!